# PHP CURL call with withCredentials/CORS

Tags: php, curl, cookies, cross-domain

I have a PHP script (script A) that sets a cookie. It's called by an AJAX JS call from a different domain (so it's using preflight CORS with the withCredentials flag set). I now want this PHP script to CURL another domain's PHP script (script B) in order for it to also set a cookie. However, I'm having trouble getting those cookies set.

The CURL is returning successful and the setcookie() in scriptB.php is returning true but the cookie is not present on the browser when a domainB.com page is loaded.

Scripts B is using the same preflight CORS concept has script A (please ignore the security risks in this code, this is in the proof-of-concept phase):

```
<?php

$allowedDomains = array('http://www.domainA.com', 'http://www.domainB.com', 'http://www.domainC.com');

// Make sure the request is from an accepted domain
if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $allowedDomains))
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Access Forbidden");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo "Access denied";
    exit;
}

// "Preflight' request required by CORS
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS')
{
    // Preflight response
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');       
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header("Content-Length: 0");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    exit;
}

// Handles the actual requests
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{

    // Get the POST data
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);


    if(!isset($obj->cv) || !isset($obj->e))
    {
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Access Forbidden");
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        echo "Access denied.";
        exit;   
    }

    $cookieValue = $_POST['cv'];
    $expires = $_POST['e'];
    if(!is_numeric($expires))
    {
        $expires = strtotime($expires);
    }

    $r = setcookie('cpn_auth',$cookieValue,$expires,'/','domainB.com',false,false);

    $response = array('result' => 1);

    sendResponse($response);

}


/**
* Sets the reply headers and outputs the reply message
*
* @param    array       $response The data to send back to the requesting script
* @return   void
*/
function sendResponse($response)
{

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;

}
```

The CURL calling this script:

```
$post = json_encode(array('cv'=>$cv, 'e'=>$e));

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domainB.com/scriptB.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user123:pass123"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain',
    'Origin: http://www.domainA.com',
    'Referer: http://www.domainA.com',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post)
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$return = json_decode($result, true);
curl_close($curl);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Or if there is an easier way? I've seen answers to somewhat similar questions that recommend setting things like CURLOPT_COOKIE, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, and CURLOPT_HEADER and I've tried them all in different ways. Either nothing changes or the CURL fails.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the cookie jar so the session will persist. Specifically, you need the cookiejar and cookiefile options set to the name of a readable/writable file.

PS: You can use `tempnam()` to create your cookiejar file.

Here's an example using the function below:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cookiejar'])) $_SESSION['cookiejar'] = tempnam();
$url = "http://www.domainB.com/scriptB.php";
$resp = request($url, null, null, $_SESSION['cookiejar']);
```

Here's a cURL function I use to log into sites and download stuff:

```
/*
* Makes an HTTP request via GET or POST, and can download a file
* @returns - Returns the response of the request
* @param $url - The URL to request, including any GET parameters
* @param $params - An array of POST values to send
* @param $filename - If provided, the response will be saved to the 
*    specified filename
*/
private static function request($url, $params = array(), $filename = "", $cookiejar=null) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlOpts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        // Set Useragent
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Rockwell Helpdesk API',
        // Don't validate SSL 
        // This is to prevent possible errors with self-signed certs
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    );
    if(!empty($cookiejar)){
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $cookiejar;
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR] = $cookiejar;
    }
    if(!empty($filename)){
        // If $filename exists, save content to file
        $file2 = fopen($filename,'w+') or die("Error[".__FILE__.":".__LINE__."] Could not open file: $filename");
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_FILE] = $file2;
    }
    if (!empty($params)) {
        // If POST values are given, send that shit too
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($params);
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    // If there was an error, show it
    if (curl_error($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
    if(!empty($filename)) fclose($file2);
    curl_close($ch);
    self::$lastRequest = $answer;
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Pamblam. Sadly it had no effect (the curl and setcookie() are still returning true but the cookie isn't showing on site load). I have a curiosity question about this command: "$curlOpts[] = $cookiejar;" What is this turning into when curl_setopt_array() is called?

Comment: `curl_setopt_array()` is simply a function that you can use to set multiple curl options at once. It would be the same thing as calling `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiejar); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejar);` Also, your `setCookie` function is going to set the cookie on the **user's** computer. When you use cURL, it's the server making the request, not the user, which is why setting a cookie on the user's computer won't do anything at all. Instead, you have to set the cookie on the **server** and the only way to do that is to set cURL's `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and

Comment: ...`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options.. make sense?

Comment: I get the functionality of curl_setopt_array() which is why "$curlOpts[] = $cookiejar;" is confusing me. "$curlOpts[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $cookiejar;" sets the value of the "CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE" option, but what option is being set for "$curlOpts[] = $cookiejar;"?

Comment: @DrewG - That's a typo.. thank you for pointing that out. I've fixed it.

Comment: "Also, your setCookie function is going to set the cookie on the user's computer." That is what I'd like to happen actually. I want the cookie to be set on the user's computer so that when they visit domainB the cookie from scriptB will be set on their browser.

Comment: @DrewG - Again though, it's not the user's computer making the request, so giving that cookie to the user is pointless. The remote server is talking to your server, not to the user's computer. However, setting the cookiejar file to the session is basically the same thing because PHP sessions are in fact, cookies.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying and I think that's why using COOKIEJAR/COOKIEFILE isn't going to get me what I need. Giving the cookie to the user is the end-goal (if by giving the cookie to the user means creating a persistent cookie on the user's browser that can be accessed by that browser when the user connects to domainB, without having to go through script A). I don't want to waste any more of your time though; I appreciate your advice and direction.

Comment: @DrewG - I see what you're trying to do now,, no, tha won't work because cookies are domain specific. DomainB can't access cookies created by domainA. :( good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Thankfully I have another, less elegant, solution if I can't get this working (that I've confirmed works): having the javascript (which initially called scriptA) create a hidden iframe (when scriptA returns successfully) that loads a script on domainB that sets the cookie for domainB. Essentially the same concept, but using an iframe client-side instead of a CURL call server-side. Cheers!

Comment: Hmm... interesting about cookie a work fine `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => null, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => null`... Thanks!!